# How to apply Solr max function for all fields

Tags: java, solr

I have a `price` field for a number of products. What would be the Solr query to apply the max function to retrieve the maximum price of all products?

Answer (score 2):

You could [group by price](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) and sort by price within that group.

Comment: yeap..this would do it also.